# Location of Zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the function 
                    $$f(z) = \cosh(z) ,\quad z \in \mathbb{C}$$
and let's take the circle $\{z: |z|=3\}$ .
While it can be seen that zeros of $f(z)$ are given by
              $$z = -i (k+1/2)π ,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
My question is how we  locate these zeros on a complex plane which (complex plane) is purely  in numbers (I.e., axis $X$ and $Y$ are numbered in integers and not in $π$ or $π/2$)
NOTE:  That all zeros may not lie in our specified circle

Comment: I have corrected some of your formulas. Learn how to use Latex/Mathjax

Comment: sorry i will definitely, being new

Comment: [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) details the most common math typesetting.

Comment: Use $\pi\approx3.14$.